# Binding an event handler to an HTML select.option

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to show a warning message if a user selects a specific option, but the warning isn't appearing. How can I modify my code so that this works correctly? Here is a [demo on jsFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ndgnvetm/2/) which reproduces the problem?

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="mail_address"/>
<select>
    <option value='google.com'>google.com</option>
    <option onClick="warningaa()" value=''>Don't send mail</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
function warningaa() {
    alert('If you choose this option, you can not receive any information');
}
```

Comment: In this case, it's broken because `warningaa()` function is defined below the HTML code. Still, it's an incorrect approach to use `onclick` for that (what if user chooses an option by keyboard?), you should listen for `onchange` on select instead.

Comment: Bind a change handler to the `select` itself, get rid of the `onclick` in your HTML, get the sequence of your scripts right: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ndgnvetm/13/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can not use on click action in dropdown option. One solution is to use `change` on select element:

**html**

```
<input type="text" id="mail_address" />
<select onchange="warningaa(this);">
    <option value='google.com'>google.com</option>
    <option value='error'>error</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
function warningaa(obj) {
    if(obj.value == "error") {
        alert('If you choose this option, you can not receive any infomation');
    }
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ndgnvetm/10/)

Answer (score 6):

The option tag does not support the onclick event. Use the onchange event on the select instead.

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="mail_address"/>
<select id="selectbox" onchange="warning(this)">
  <option value='google.com'>google.com</option>
  <option value='warning'>Do not send me any kind of shit</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function warning(obj) {
  if(obj.value == 'warning') {
    alert('If you choose this option, you can not receive any infomation');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set an event handler on the SELECT element, and watch the "value" of select, as below:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', warn, true);
function warn(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (e.currentTarget.value === 'the value you want') {
    // do something
  } else {
  return;
}
```

The key here is using CHANGE event vs CLICK, since you want to react to a "change in value" and if that value = something, warn the user.
using addEventListener is also a better approach overall, it clearly distinguishes your HTML from your JavaScript.

More on this here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

and here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event