# Event Listener - change not working after page load

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to have a drop-down update and change the html page by hiding or revealing another drop-down (Or even disable it) (In this case, the "provider-selection".)

However, the event listener is not triggering properly (It triggers on-load, but not dynamically if I change the report-selection select element.

I have tried various if conditions. Nothing triggers. If I put a console.log before the if statement, it will show the console log, but nothing else after that (Such as the logs from within the if conditions.

I have confirmed through other tests that the js file loads properly at the end of the file (I left out some other functions that take effect on page load. They are simpler such as changing text)

Looking for someone to point me in the right direction to learn and figure out what I am doing wrong. I would like to keep the functions for hide_element / unhide_element if possible for code re-usability, but if that's not possible, I would like to know what is the best practice for this type of scenario.

HTML

```
<section>
    <nav>
        <select id="report-selection">
            <option id="report-types" value="null">Pick One</option>
            <option id="report-types" value="AR">Accounts Receivable</option>
            <option id="report-types" value="Production">Daily Production</option>
        </select>
        
        <br>
        <select id="office-selection">
            <option id="office-1" value="office-1">Test-Office 1</option>
            <option id="office-2" value="office-2">Test-Office 2</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <select id="provider-selection">
            <option id="provider-1" value="provider-1">Test-Provider 1</option>
            <option id="provider-2" value="provider-2">Test-Provider 2</option>
        </select>
        </br>
</section>
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
/**********  Report Selection Hide / Show Elements  ***************/
const report_type_selector = document.getElementById('report-types');
const provider = document.getElementById('provider-selection');

report_type_selector.addEventListener("change", provider_field_change);

function provider_field_change(){
    if (report_type_selector.value == 'AR') {      
        hide_element(provider);
        console.log("AR event triggered");
    } 
    if (report_type_selector.value == 'Production') {
        unhide_element(provider);
        console.log("Production event triggered");
    }
}

function hide_element(id) {
    id.style.display = 'none';
}

function unhide_element(id) {
    id.style.display = 'block';
}
/******************************************************************/
```

Edit:
The automated system stated this was a duplicate of this: [addEventListener calls the function without me even asking it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310423/addeventlistener-calls-the-function-without-me-even-asking-it-to)

Edit 2:
Thanks to Nick, he was able to point out where I was wrong.

Please close this, as it is resolved.

Comment: It should be `addEventListener("change", provider_field_change);` so no `()` after `provider_field_change`

Comment: That unfortunetly does not give me the results I am looking for.
When I change it to Accounts Receiveable, it does not make the provider dropdown disappear

Comment: You should also be using `const report_type_selector = document.getElementById('report-selection');`, so your `id` selector should be on the `select` tag. Also, each element should have unique ids, you don't really need to have an `id` attribute on your `<option>` tags.

Comment: So you have two issues, the one in the duplicate and the other is that you're not selecting the correct element. The duplicate isn't necessarily wrong and is the primary issue as to why your function is running on load that you asked about.

Comment: Thank you Nick. That answered my question.
So I understand this right, I should use the parent, in this case the select id, not the option id.

Option ID should not need to be used.

Comment: Yeah, the `change` event triggers on the `select` element, not the individual options :)

Comment: I wish there was a way to give you the resolution points :( However, I do not see that as an option.

Comment: There typically is, but as your question was closed as a duplicate of another, my "answer" was provided as a comment, not an official answer (which can't be added now as your question is closed). The question can be reopened if there isn't another question that asks the same thing relating to adding change events to options vs select element (but I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25847829/binding-an-event-handler-to-an-html-select-option) is quite similar)

Comment: I am voting to reopen so that it can be answered